# Android Gradle ResolutionStrategy force stil downloads previous version of lib

Tags: java, android, gradle, findbugs

I have forced in my gradle to download this version of jsr305 as follows :

```
resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
```

I see that when I try to compile the gradle is resolving the version :
[image: gradle resolution for module 1]

[image: gradle resolution for module 2]

Inspite of that I see that during gradle sync the older versions (2.0.1 & 1.3.9) are still getting downloaded :

[image]

I am getting compile errors as follows :
`com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
Error while generating the main dex list.
com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: javax.annotation.CheckForNull` 
`Program type already present: javax.annotation.CheckForNull`

I did a module level search and found that the `CheckForNull.java` is present at multiple places in 
`jsr305/2.0.1
jsr305/3.0.1
jsr305/1.3.9`

I have tried deleting `./gradle` folder and resync the project. I see that gradle still downloads the previous jsr305 version.

These are my dependencies in gradle :

`implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:${versions.reactNative}"
 implementation ("com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:3.0.1") {
        exclude group: 'net.jcip', module: 'jcip-annotations'
    }`

My questions :

1. Why is Gradle still downloading the older version of jsr305 ?
2. And in spite of the jsr305 version getting resolved why is multidex throwing that error ?

Created a test project that shows the behavior where the old lib versions are downloaded even after the forced resolution:
https://github.com/vineyugave/scratchpad

Also you can see the gradle scan here :
https://scans.gradle.com/s/tzrobr2zuar3c/dependencies?dependencies=jsr&expandAll

Comment: could you please add the dependencies from the `build.gradle`?

Comment: Added the dependencies in original post as requested.@MartinZeitler

Comment: ... the full `dependencies {}` & `resolutionStrategy` and not just a tiny snippet. else this question is impossible to answer properly; in best case could close it for being "too broad" or "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: the whole dependency list consists of some private libs and code that I cant post.. what exactly were you looking for ?

Comment: looking for code which I can simply paste into a `build.gradle`, which is good enough to reproduce the issue... then it would be easy for me to answer both questions.

Comment: @MartinZeitler added  a link to the test project that shows this behavior

Comment: @MartinZeitler you can. look at the build gradle here : https://github.com/vineyugave/scratchpad

Answer (score 0):

module `:firstlib` references `implementation "com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.0"`,
which should possibly be `implementation "com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2"` ...but the other one `build.gradle` does not really match the question, because it lacks `react-native`.

the `dependencies` of module `:app` should look alike (only the changes):

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
    implementation ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1") {
        exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "recyclerview-v7"
        exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-v4"
    }
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "com.google.guava:guava:24.1-android"

}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2"
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.guava:guava:24.1-android"
}
```

- it's downloading elder versions, because they would need to be explicitly excluded from the dependencies, which demand them (as demonstrated above). one can list them all with `./gradlew app:dependencies` and then `exclude` them accordingly.
- task `:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug` failed, because of support-library version conflicts caused by `react-native` (already fixed in the above example).
- when moving those `jniLibs` from `armeabi` into `armeabi-v7a`, it wouldn't complain about a missing stripping tool anymore. however, then they wouldn't be loaded on `arm64-v8a` anymore.

Comment: Is there any possible explanation as to why when I run Proguard ON it compiles fine ?